# Query Collection for Subsets

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to query a mongo collection for documents that are subsets of my object (query).
e.g.

```
object:
{
     "animal": "cat"
    ,"owner": "mike"
    ,"color": "blue"
    ,"city": "houston"
}

collection:
[
    [0]{
         "color": "red"
        ,"animal": "cat"
    }
    [1]{
         "color": "blue"
    }
    [2]{
         "owner": "mike"
        ,"city": "houston"
    }
]

result:
    [1]{
        "color": "blue"
    }
    [2]{
         "owner": "mike"
        ,"city": "houston"
    }
```

Comment: what's the object represent?  the possible attributes in the collection?

Comment: The object can be any json object. I want to find any documents in the collection that are subsets of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build the query dynamically based on the properties of the JavaScript object.

The query would be something like:

```
$and : [
    {$or : [{ color: { $exists: true, $eq: 'blue' } }, {color: { $exists:false} }]},
    {$or : [{ owner: { $exists: true, $eq: 'mike' } }, {owner: { $exists:false} }]},
    ...
    // iterate through the other properties.
]
```

**EDIT:**

Using the `$and` means that is the documents in collection have the property they all must match the `object` - you could change to `$or` to match any of the attributes.

**EDIT 2**

Also worth considering performance will be poor for large collections if you don't use indexed attributes in the query. One solution to your problem would be to use an array and a multikey index.

i.e.

```
{ tags : [ "color=blue","owner=mike" ] }
```

this way you can use the regex `\^color=\` to return all docs with class= tag and use the index.  You could also do \^color=blue\ for blues.

Then to do multiple conditions you would use the `$all` or `$in` operators.

E.g.

```
{ tags : { $in: [/^color=blue/, /^owner=mike/]} }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried this last night. The problem is that using this pattern is that an object having properties that do no exists in a document will still have that document in the results set because we are accepting documents where fields don't exist.

`$and : [
    {$or : [{ color: { $exists: true, $eq: 'blue' } }, {color: { $exists:false} }]}
]`

This will pull back all documents.

Comment: That is very true, have you considered my alternative idea?

Comment: The only other way of using that pattern would be to build permutations of the different combinations of conditions.  It would be a much bigger query, but still generated dynamically.

Comment: I was hoping for some voodoo magic. Including each different combination in a large $or query would in theory work in a brute force kind of way. I don't think this will scale very gracefully however if you have queries that are larger than a few key value pairs.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in here, I'm going through the same thing, built something very similar then realized like you did that it ends up accepting documents where fields don't exist. I came across this post on mongodb.org's issue manager that does what were trying to accomplish I think, it's not implemented though and not on the immediate roadmap either. Would be very interested to hear if you figured out a way to do this efficiently.. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-974?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel